# How do I get the current model from custom method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, models

I'm not sure I am asking the questions correctly, but this is what I am trying to do.

So we can get the current from

**`$model = Model::find($id)`**

Then we can get it's relationships like:

**`$model->relationships()->id`**

Then we have actions like:

**`$model->relationships()->detach(4);`**

My question is, can we have a custom method like:

**`$model->relationships()->customMethod($params);`**?

and in the model it may look like:

```
   public function customMethod($params){
         //Do something with relationship id
   }
```

But further more, how in the `customMethod` would I get the `$models` info like id?

Sorry if this may be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all**, if you want to access a related object, you do this by accessing an attribute with the same name as the relation. In your case, in order to access object(s) from **relationships**, you need to do this by:

```
$model->relationships //returns related object or collection of objects
```

instead of

```
$model->relationships() //returns relation definition
```

**Secondly**, if you want to access attributes on the related object, you can do it the same way:

```
$relatedObjectName = $model->relationship->name; // this works if you have a single object on the other end of relations
```

**Lastly**, if you want to call a method on a related model you need to implement this method in related model class.

```
class A extends Eloquent {
  public function b() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Some\Namespace\B');
  }

  public function cs() {
    return $this->hasMany('Some\Namespace\C');
  }
}

class B extends Eloquent {
  public function printId() {
    echo $this->id;
  }
}

class C extends Eloquent {
  public function printId() {
    echo $this->id;
  }
}

$a = A::find(5);
$a->b->printId(); //call method on related object
foreach ($a->cs as $c) { //iterate the collection
  $c->printId(); //call method on related object
}
```

You can read more about how to define and use relationships here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Ok, I follow, does this work if the relationship is more than one? given your  example, would it print out all the IDs?

Comment: If you have have a collection of objects you need to iterate through the collection and call it on every object. I've updated the answer